# Export Json to CSV with missing key in a dict via get()

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, key

I am very new to Python, and need to using Python to get the below work done.

I am using Python to get value out for a key pairs (which is the JSON response I got from API call), however, some of them has the value while some of them might not have the value, example of JSON response as below:

```
"attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "TK_GENIE_ACTUAL_TOTAL_HOURS_EXCLUDE_CORRECTIONS",
                    "alias": "Annual Leave"
                },
                {
                    "key": "TK_GENIE_ACTUAL_TOTAL_HOURS_EXCLUDE_CORRECTIONS",
                    "alias": "Other Non-Prod Hours"
                },
                {
                    "key": "TK_GENIE_ACTUAL_TOTAL_HOURS_EXCLUDE_CORRECTIONS",
                    "alias": "Non-Prod Hours"
                },
                {
                    "key": "EMP_COMMON_PRIMARY_JOB",
                    "alias": "Primary Job",
                    "rawValue": "RN",
                    "value": "RN"
                },
                {
                    "key": "TIMECARD_TRANS_APPLY_DATE",
                    "alias": "Apply Date",
                    "rawValue": "2022-05-19",
                    "value": "19/05/2022"
                },
```

The above is one of the children under a nested others, as you can see, for the above one, there is no value for "Annual Leave", however, other children might has a valid value for "Annual Leave"

I am exporting those infor into CSV, with "alias" is the column name, and "value" is the row value
like below csv sample:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W00MY.png)

So, I using the below python code to extract the value for each key and put them into csv as per column specified.

```
            AL=item['attributes'][0]['value']
            Date=item['attributes'][4]['value']
            spamwriter.writerow([AL,'2','3',date,'5'])
```

However, it raised an error code

```
 File "jsoncsv.py", line 47, in <module>
al=item['attributes'][0]['value']
 KeyError: 'value'
```

I think I understand the error, where there is no value for this particular "Annual Leave" key.
But how do I say,like, if there is no value for this key, then value = 0, and put 0 in the CSV under "Annual Leave" column, then, move to next (which is "Other Non-Prod Hours", which also has no value in this case, but might have value for some other children)?

I found get(), but not sure how should I code it, I was trying below code:

```
            value=it.get('value')
            if len(value)>0:
            AL=item['attributes'][0]value
            Date=item['attributes'][4]value
            spamwriter.writerow([AL,'2','3',date,'5'])
```

But result is syntax error.

Could please any Python expert provide help.

Much Appreciated.

WB

Comment: Try `al=item['attributes'][0].get('value', 0)`.  Calling `.get()` on a dictionary will retrieve the key, and unless a default value is specified, it will return `None` if the key doesn't exist.  If you want something like 0, then you specify 0 as the default.

Answer (score 0):

As user @richarddodson pointed out, you can do this:

```
al = item['attributes'][0].get('value', 0)
```

Instead of `0`, you may want to consider using `None`, which is a clear indication that there is no value, avoiding confusion with the case where value actually *is* `0`, i.e.:

```
al = item['attributes'][0].get('value', None)
```

Which is the same as:

```
al = item['attributes'][0].get('value')
```

As `.get()` returns `None` if there is no value to get.

A more explicit way to do the same would be:

```
al = None if 'value' in item['attributes'][0] else item['attributes'][0]['value']
```

But the solution using `.get()` is simpler and faster and thus probably preferable.

Comment: If you feel this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark to accept it, so it no longer appears as unanswered and give Richard an upvote to his comment to your question, as I have.